# Linq Query to excel export

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have one application where I used LINQ to load data in grid view. It has around 2 million records. For loading gridview I am able to show data in gridview but I need to have their export functionality. For that purpose, i am using LINQ skip and take procedure like LINQ query to get data in batch-wise.

After that, i am converting LINQ query to data table then doing the export.

Below is the code for converting linq query to datatable:

```
 public DataTable LINQToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> varlist)
{
            DataTable dtReturn = new DataTable();

            // column names 
            PropertyInfo[] oProps = null;

            if (varlist == null) return dtReturn;

            foreach (T rec in varlist)
            {
                // Use reflection to get property names, to create table, Only first time, others will follow 
                if (oProps == null)
                {
                    oProps = ((Type)rec.GetType()).GetProperties();
                    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in oProps)
                    {
                        Type colType = pi.PropertyType;

                        if ((colType.IsGenericType) && (colType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)))
                        {
                            colType = colType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                        }

                        dtReturn.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(pi.Name, colType));
                    }
                }

                DataRow dr = dtReturn.NewRow();

                foreach (PropertyInfo pi in oProps)
                {
                    dr[pi.Name] = pi.GetValue(rec, null) == null ? DBNull.Value : pi.GetValue
                    (rec, null);
                }

                dtReturn.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            return dtReturn;
        }
```

And after that export code which is below:

```
private void ExportToExcel(DataTable dt)
{
                try
                {
                    Response.ClearContent();
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "CustomReport.xls"));
                    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
                    string str = string.Empty;
                    foreach (DataColumn dtcol in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        Response.Write(str + dtcol.ColumnName);
                        str = "\t";
                    }
                    Response.Write("\n");
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        str = "";
                        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                        {
                            Response.Write(str + Convert.ToString(dr[j]).Replace("\r\n", string.Empty).Trim());
                            str = "\t";
                        }
                        Response.Write("\n");
                    }
                    Response.End();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
```

The issue here if I do an export in batch-wise like 500 000 records then two times I am able to export but when going for third 500k record export then getting out of memory exception in the **linqToDataTable** method.

Is there any other simple way to export without having out of memory exception?

Comment: A GridView with 2 million records souns like a very bad idea to me.

Comment: @S.Akbari, I think moreLinq should work, I have gone through this link and got to know that for installing this i need nuget package manager console. I tried to install nuget package manager which installed with version 2.8 and when tried to install morelinq then got error that we require 2.12 version of nuget package manager. Please suggest me how do i install this as i have some issue with morelinq installation. Currently using .net version 4.0.